# Git Bash behavior changed after Windows restart - won't run login script on launch

Tags: git, windows-10, git-bash

After a Windows 10 restart, Git Bash behavior changed.

Previously I used to get like below

[image: before]

After Windows 10 restart, I get like below. Looks like it isn't executing the login script on launch.

[image: after]

Also get this warning now

[image: warning]

Reinstallation of Git doesn't help.